# Pass new line \n character through windows command line

Tags: node.js, docker, ssh, cmd, rsa

I need to run a docker command that takes an ssh private key as argument

```
docker build --build-arg ssh_prv_key="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
asfasfsaasdadfafaafafaaQsiuyTei9MHdDAmjk1XgDsdgsgrrjtjtjtwwswCLa
HYtZKnABR6e5+dSnqcspadfafafswwttryryeyeryeyreryeryeyUKQ3MRstyynB... and so on"
```

The problem is that windows do not allow newline characters in the command line and, it says

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

Removing all the line feeds is not ok as the ssh key is not recognized anymore.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This problem in Linux / Mac is solved by doing `docker build --build-arg ssh_prv_key=$(cat ssh_key)`

I'm not a Windows user, so can't test. But if you use PowerShell, you can use the same. Maybe replacing `cat` for `type` (dunno if `cat` exists nowadays in Windows)